# Simple type test in F#

Tags: f#, c#-to-f#

I've been googling for a while now... Ok, I'm sorry, this one is pathetically easy but is there an operator in F# to compare class types, like the 'is' keyword in C#? I don't want to use a full blown match statement or start casting things. Cheers

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use the `:?` construct both as a pattern (inside `match`) or as an operator:

```
let foo = bar :? System.Random
```

This behaves slightly differently than in C#, because the compiler still tries to do some checks at compile-time. For example, it is an error to use this if the result would be surely `false`:

```
let bar = 42
let foo = bar :? System.Random // Error
```

I don't think this could lead to confusion, but you can always add `box` to convert the argument to `obj`, which can be tested against any type:

```
let foo = box bar :? System.Random
```

Comment: I think that has done it... If I play around with it in the interactive window it keeps giving "Type constraint mismatch" errors if they are not the same type which threw me off the scent a bit... it seems to work fine in the actual editor.

Comment: @Ciemnl - I added some information about possible source of confusing warnings. I'm not sure how you can get "type constraint mismatch" though.

Comment: yeah that was why... the compiler was being too clever with my quick test to see if it worked. I underestimated F#! I'm really impressed with the language come to think of it...

Answer (score 6):

If you want a general C#-to-F# quick-reference, see

http://lorgonblog.wordpress.com/2008/11/28/what-does-this-c-code-look-like-in-f-part-one-expressions-and-statements/

which answers this question and many others.